# pressure in boiler getting too high

Tags: boiler, hydronic

The pressure relief valve on the hydronic system boiler is releasing a little water every time the boiler cycle is almost done and I looked at the gage and its rising to about 30 psi, But I can't figure why the temp is always rising.   I already changed the expension tank and TPR so whats now?

Comment: What is your normal boiler pressure? When you changed the expansion tank, what did you set the pre-fill pressure to?

Comment: @ Ecnerwal normal pressure is about 15 psi. the tank comes pre-filled to 12 psi

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an [automatic fill valve](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/84366/how-to-get-heating-system-working-again/84369#84369)? Is there a manual valve in line with it? Try closing the manual valve if there is one. If that solves your problem, adjust and/or replace the automatic fill valve.

If you have a (domestic/potable) hot water coil, that could be leaking into the boiler, too. Shut off the domestic hot water supply on the cold side of the boiler to diagnose that possibility.

Comment: I just changed the pressure regulator to a new one (15 psi) and the problem persists

Comment: Have you tried shutting OFF the supply to the system (which I suggested doing **before** you wandered off into replacing parts that might not be broken?) And the supply to a domestic hot water coil, if any (or simply shutoff the main water supply valve for a while which should cover both of those, and then work backwards from what that indicates.)

Comment: Yes I did shut off the water and the pressure did not rise and no dripping.

Comment: No hot water coil