# Water does not come out of radiator

Tags: furnace, boiler

I went to bleed a radiator today and although a little bit of air came out, it stopped and no water came out even though the heat is on.

I went to the boiler and the pressure was only 8 PSI.

There is a valve near the expansion tank that seems to be where cold water can enter the system. I tried opening this valve and the pressure slowly rose to about 12 PSI. (feel like I am operating a submarine here) Should I continue and let more air into the system until it is a higher pressure?

Shouldn't the system automatically be drawing in water if it needs it?

Comment: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/84366/how-to-get-heating-system-working-again/84369#84369  Auto-fill is a double-edge sword - if the system needs auto-filling, it's leaking, and if you just keep adding water (automatically, so you are not even aware of it) it will rust like crazy if it's the typical mixture of iron pumps and boiler and copper or PEX pipes. So it's fairly normal to need manual operation to fill the system.

Answer (score 1):

Some sediment seems to have blocked the valve.

According to a technician, what I did was the correct thing to do. Opening the valve clears any sediment that was there and causes the valve to function normally afterwards.